# Set password for user that is already signed in with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have the following situation:

Users can sign-up in my web application with **single sign on**.  In that case there is no password set.  I mark this in the users table with the boolean column **no_password_set**.

In the settings page when I see the boolean is true, instead of giving the users the option to choose a new password, I have put a button which sends them a mail with a link to set a password.

For this I use devise: **send_reset_password_instructions** and in the email template I change the text a bit so *Forgot password* is changed to *Set a password*.

So far so good, however when a user clicks the link they get a message saying: **You are already signed in.**  How can I avoid this?  I want the users to only be able to choose a password after they confirm this through their mail.  Otherwise an attacker could open the browser on somebody's pc, set a password and use that.

Logging the user out when he clicks on the link to set a password would be acceptable too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a working solution for this.

Create this controller:

```
class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: [:cancel ]

end
```

And alter routes file like this:

```
  devise_for :user, controllers: { passwords: 'passwords' }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully that'll work...

```
class Devise::PasswordsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_action :remove_session, only: [:edit]
  prepend_before_action :require_no_authentication

  private
   def remove_session
     sign_out resource if user_signed_in?
   end 
end
```

Comment: you can see the sign_out documentation here [link](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_out-instance_method)

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.

Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"}
  User Load (4.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
Redirected to http://lvh.me:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 148ms (ActiveRecord: 14.1ms)

Comment: can you please try ' sign_out resource ' without if condition, as there is no need of it , and make sure statement is running by putting ' byebug ' before this statement.

Comment: It never hits that part.